# ffmpeg monochrome rawvideo

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, monochrome

I am trying to generate a raw video stream with luma only (monochrome, YUV400) 8bit pixel data using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt raw.yuv
```

After that I want to h.264 encode the raw stream with the profiles that support monochrome pixel data (eg: high)

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -s 640x512 -r 60 -i raw.yuv -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -c:a copy out.mp4
```

However, i always get the following error, which indicates that the raw stream is not in the monochrome format that I expected:

```
x264 [error]: high profile doesn't support 4:4:4
```

I am new to ffmpeg and video formats in general. Can somebody please point out what I am missing?

Thank you!

**Edit:**
I also tried to use the following filter to extract only the luma channel. Unfortunately, the end result was the same.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -filter_complex 'extractplanes=y[y]' -map '[y]' raw.yuv
```

Answer (score 0):

The ffmpeg version installed was quite old (3.4.7). After installing 4.2.3 everything worked fine.